# How to get transloco to read from different files

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, transloco

I am using in an Angular project transloco for multilanguage. In this project, I am also importing a micro frontend with modules federation. The microfront module have its own translation dictionary file that works fine, but once it is imported in the shell, it seems that transloco only used the file of the shell module, not the microfront.
Is it there any way to tell transloco to read from more than one file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple loaders via `TranslocoModule`.

**For example:**

```
TranslocoModule({
    loader: {
        provide: TranslocoLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslocoHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json'),
        deps: [HttpClient]
    },
    additionalLangs: ['en'],
    missingHandler: { use: MyMissingHandler },
    extend: {
        services: [
          { provide: TranslocoService, useClass: MyService },
        ],
        config: {
          ...
        }
      }
})
```

Make sure to read these [changes in transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/migration/ngx/#modules), so you can use **TranslocoModule**.